# Why does str_replace not correctly replace these extended ascii characters?

Tags: php, extended-ascii

This is a UTF-8 encoded source file. I must be missing something obvious, but I've tried all the permutations I can think of.

```
<?php

$bad =  array( chr(130), chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(173), chr(160) );
$good = array( chr( 44), chr( 39), chr( 39), chr( 34), chr( 34), chr( 45), chr( 45), chr( 45), chr( 32) );

print_r($bad);
print_r($good);

 $str = <<<EOF
    bad comma ‚
    bad quote ‘
    bad quote ’
    bad quote “
    bad quote ”
    bad dash –
    bad dash —
    bad dash ­
    bad space   

EOF;
    echo $str;
    $clean = str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
    echo "\n";
    echo( $clean);
```

And when I open it in a browser and view source...

```
Array
(
    [0] => ‚
    [1] => ‘
    [2] => ’
    [3] => “
    [4] => ”
    [5] => –
    [6] => —
    [7] => ­
    [8] =>  
)
Array
(
    [0] => ,
    [1] => '
    [2] => '
    [3] => "
    [4] => "
    [5] => -
    [6] => -
    [7] => -
    [8] =>  
)
    bad comma â€š
    bad quote â€˜
    bad quote â€™
    bad quote â€œ
    bad quote â€
    bad dash â€“
    bad dash â€”
    bad dash Â­
    bad space   

    bad comma â€š
    bad quote â€˜
    bad quote â€™
    bad quote â€œ
    bad quote â€
    bad dash â€"
    bad dash â€"
    bad dash Â-
    bad space
```

Comment: Does the browser know it's UTF-8?

Comment: @MrLister - That's not really the point because the replacement of the characters is supposed to happen server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between ASCII, Multibyte and UTF-8.

In your case those characters are Multibyte Characters. *"Multibyte" is just an arbitrary non-UTF-8 encoding.*

you could convert them to UTF-8 first or use [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)

Most PHP Devs don't know much about Character Encoding, but it's one of the most important things when working in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go and try this now. And you're right about this PHP dev if not others :)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php thats why PHP has alot of Multibyte functions :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried mb_ functions in all sorts of ways and still couldn't figure it out. I ended up using urlencode then str_replace then urldecode. A nasty hack but it gets me a step further forward.

Comment: you could try: this sample code.... $newtext = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text); then do the str_replace on $newtext

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting problems because the uploaded csv file might have encoding different to that expected. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I've got a bit more understanding of the problem (only a bit, though). Using vi, I've opened up the csv file that I need to parse and the comma that I inserted before upload was ascii 130 but has now become e2 80 9a in utf8. Somehow I need to make sure that the encoding will always be the same and then search and replace the utf8 versions of the bad characters. I think.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've used your iconv suggestion to put it back into ISO and I reckon I'm nearly there now. Thanks a lot.